# How to prevent prefers-reduced-motion setting from ever working in Chrome

Tags: windows-10, google-chrome, web-development, accessibility, system-preferences

[Since Chrome version 74](https://blog.logrocket.com/new-in-chrome-74-prefers-reduced-motion-media-query-50cd89d3e769/), `prefers-reduced-motion` media queries will be set with `reduce` value in case the user [has disabled animations in controls inside Windows](https://developer.paciellogroup.com/blog/2019/05/short-note-on-prefers-reduced-motion-and-puzzled-windows-users/).

I'm on Win 10 and use mostly Chrome for testing. Animations weren't working on my computer but looked fine on other machines. After googling it, I re-enabled animations in controls inside Windows and voila - they started working.

That said, I think it's **pretty annoying** that we don't have a way to tell Chrome not to follow these system-wide flags. I disable most of Windows's standard animations because I favor performance instead of cumbersome "eye-candies" - but as a web developer, I want them on in Chrome *regardless* of however I want my OS in general to behave.

I tried looking for Chrome extensions but to no avail. Also looked for settings inside `chrome://flags` and wasn't able to find anything.

Am I missing anything? Are there any ways I can intervene with Chrome trying to be helpful and being extremely inconvenient instead?

---

Just to be thoroughly clear:

I want Windows animations under System > Properties > Performance > Settings to be turned off, including **animate controls inside Windows**, but [still be able to see animations in **Chrome**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/@media/prefers-reduced-motion#Result) (if the purple box in this link pulsates, then it is working).

Comment: Why do you wish to override user preferences? And why are you using `prefers-reduced-motion` if you don't want it?

Comment: Because
1. **I** am the OS user, but
2. my application's user **will be someone else**.

I want it on in **Windows** (my **personal** preference).

I don't want it on in **Chrome**, because I _need_ to have the same experience as my user to check whether it feels acceptable or not.

Comment: Install an extension like Greasemonkey  to get rid of the `prefers-reduced-motion`.

Comment: It seem you can enforce the reduced motion with a command line flag, but not disable it. `brave-browser --force-prefers-reduced-motion` will do the trick.

Comment: Same boat as you. I don't want my Windows apps animating my menus... but as a web dev I need to see the animations on the web.  Ridiculous that Chrome devs didn't consider this when testing.

Comment: This article explains a Windows workaround that can tide us over until Chrome adds a setting for it. https://www.tpgi.com/short-note-on-prefers-reduced-motion-and-puzzled-windows-users/

Comment: I can't believe it's been 2 years and Chrome users don't have a solution for this. Firefox already has an override for this.

Comment: Sadly, @Costa's linked fix above really is the best (and only) fix for this right now. Specifically, *only* checking "Animate controls and elements inside windows" while ensuring everything else remains off. Unfortunately that seems like the only way to really resolve this for now. I appreciate that Chrome automates this, but ideally they should make an easily accessible override (especially in DevTools, which really doesn't exist yet since the current doesn't properly *enable* the preference, only disable).

Answer (score 2):

Using Chrome DevTools's [Command Menu](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/devtools/command-menu/):

1. Open Chrome DevTools and press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>P</kbd> on Windows/Linux or <kbd>Cmd</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>P</kbd> on macOS to open the Command Menu;
2. Type `reduced` to filter available commands;
3. Select the **emulate CSS prefers-reduced-motion option**, and then press <kbd>Enter</kbd> to toggle the emulation on/off;
4. Refresh the webpage and check whether your animations run.

Comment: Although this is very useful information, it doesn't solve the actual issue as described in the question. This only works _the other way around_, if you actually want to **force reduced motion**, _not_ **force animations in a reduced-motion environment**.

Answer (score 1):

You can use Firefox instead of Chrome and change the setting in `about:config`. Setting the `ui.prefersReducedMotion` as an integer with a 0.

Comment: But OP wants to use Chrome

Comment: I can't find that setting. Has it been removed?

Comment: You have to add it, see https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/@media/prefers-reduced-motion: "In Firefox about:config: Add a number preference called ui.prefersReducedMotion and set its value to either 0 for full animation or to 1 to indicate a preference for reduced motion. Changes to this preference take effect immediately". I can confirm that this works in Firefox 92.0.

Answer (score 0):

If you wish to disable the `prefers-reduced-motion` option in the CSS, use a browser
extension/add-on to remove it when it is not needed.

You may use:

- Firefox : [Greasemonkey](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/greasemonkey/)
- Chrome : [Tampermonkey](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/tampermonkey/dhdgffkkebhmkfjojejmpbldmpobfkfo?hl=en)

For information about manipulating the CSS see for example
[Manipulating Stylesheets with Greasemonkey](https://www.abeautifulsite.net/manipulating-stylesheets-with-greasemonkey).

Comment: I do use **ViolentMonkey**, which is pretty much the same thing.

The problem is I need to pass `no-preference` to the media queries for them to work as expected. The only way your suggestion would be feasible AFAIK would be to override every single `prefers-reduced-motion` rule defined in Bootstrap with the `!important` marker. Not only this is a bit clumsy, it's also potentially short-lived, since every new rule added to `prefers-reduced-motion` would not be overwritten by my custom rules.

Comment: You can inject into the page a `window.onload` function that updates the CSS by looping through all nodes that contain the wrong `prefers-reduced-motion` value and modifying it to do no animation. See the [HTML DOM querySelectorAll() Method](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_element_queryselectorall.asp) using a [CSS Selector](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_selectors.asp).

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong, but there is no way I can magically select every single element that is affected by media queries, since they are affected by the environment, not the DOM. I can hold my own pretty well with `document.querySelectorAll()` and CSS selectors, I just don't think what you propose is anywhere feasible. I will update my question with a more detailed example of what I'm trying to achieve.

Comment: You may inject `prefers-reduced-motion: reduce` to all `@media` tags. Or as a stronger method you could run Chrome in a sandbox in which animations are disabled system-wise (see [Sandboxie](https://www.sandboxie.com/)).

Comment: ... or enable animations in the sandbox, as required.